# request data from php with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to learn Ajax and Json so I can build on it to pass php data to my web page with out refreshing.
I am using the following example but the result html page does not show anything. Can some one please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Html code

```
<html>
<body>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.php",
      dataType: "json", //the return type data is jsonn
      success: function(data){ // <--- (data) is in json format
        alert(data.test1);
        //parse the json data
      }
    });
</script>
<div id = "data"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code named test.php

```
<?php

$test = array();
$test['test1'] = '1';
$test['test2'] = '2';
$test['test3'] = '3';

echo json_encode($test);
//echo nothing after this //not even html
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Check your Jquery code file in the same directory and it is valid.
2. Your php file is also in the same directory.
3. You must run your html file using localhost.

Comment: i have added this but still nothing showing on the html page

Comment: Does your jquery file is included properly?

Comment: what do you mean by jquery file included properly. all the code for the two files are shown above

Comment: do you have the jquery file in the same folder of html file?

Comment: First, adding `type: "POST"` does nothing to answer the question here. The op is clearly not trying to send any data. They're trying to receive. The HTTP request verb is irrelevant. @user2669997 Second, why are you expecting anything to show up on the page? Your code only uses an `alert`.

Comment: and also check your php file in the same folder. do not forget to run it using your localhost.

Comment: got it working it was the jquery file, I have downloaded the new file and updated the header and I now get the alert box with the result "1". Thanks Neel

Comment: @user2669997 Welcome

Comment: @Sherif My first answer was like a stupid. LOL. Because there was  nothing to do with `type:'POST`'

Comment: @NeelIon understandable. The question was rather dubious.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set response content type in php.

I think jQuery checks response type.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Also add bindings for errors.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  dataType: "json", //the return type data is jsonn
  success: function(data){ // <--- (data) is in json format
    alert(data.test1);
    //parse the json data
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Error: " + textStatus);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have added the header in the php file just under <?php and also the error part in the html script but still nothing is showing.

Comment: ajax request either falls to success or error. Check for syntax error.

Comment: Also check for semantic errors. Using your browser's debugging feature.